# What's the best way to see cpu usage breakdown for a given process?

Tags: central-processing-unit

I'm trying to find the bottlenecks and I'm currently logging the time in the script but it seems to be random times for certain operations. Is there a tool that will allow me to see the breakdown of what's going on during a certain [apache] request to track down if the CPU is just burning the whole time or if it's waiting for something else?

Comment: Missed a tiny detail...what operating system?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of profiling; you need to hook up a profiling tool to the process and get it what's really going on.  For really poor-man's profiling, I just attach to it using strace; using the timing flags (`-T -r`) usually gives me a good idea of what system calls are taking the time, and whether the process itself is just grinding along.  There are better things out there, but they're more developer-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a windows OS, then the free tools from SysInternals might be the best place to start. The [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) tool is pretty good at watching the active processes, what's calling them, and what actions are taking place. SysInternals makes it pretty easy to [download the SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) of tools. It's kinda like an American Express Card, don't leave home with it.

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to check, If you're able, is to monitor the server's performance.

Maybe your disk queues are spiking, maybe you have a failing drive in the RAID, maybe you are running out of memory, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can see some more detail with a tool like [procstat](http://brokestream.com/procstat.html).  You feed it a PID and it decodes the /proc/$pid/stat file which can tell you some interesting internals stuff, like number of CPU jiffies it has used, or its children have used.